# PHP site no longer working on Heroku: error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku, cleardb

I'm trying to push an app that I wrote in vanilla PHP 7.2.1 to Heroku. I've developed in a local docker container with apache and mariaDB and things work fine. When I go to Heroku, the index page loads, but if I try to log in or go to any other page, nothing works and I get a blank page. I use the clearDB add on and simply imported my mariaDB .sql export file in there through CLI. The website uses URL rewriting, a router and a .htaccess.

I've read through other questions here and it seems like the problem could come from multiple angles. Unfortunately I'm new to a lot of this and I struggle understanding the error logs. I think either of these (or all) could be wrong:

possible issues due to the .htaccess

lack of composer.json file, so the server end of things is configured wrong

maybe a conflict in how the database is connected to the app

Based on the information below, what could / should I try to troubleshoot the app?

This is my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]*)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is the build log:

```
-----> PHP app detected

 !     WARNING: No 'composer.json' found!
 !     Your project only contains an 'index.php', no 'composer.json'.
 !     Using 'index.php' to declare app type as PHP is deprecated and
 !     may lead to unexpected behavior.
 !     Please consider updating your codebase to utilize Composer and
 !     modern dependency management in order to benefit from the latest
 !     PHP runtimes and improved application performance, as well as
 !     control over the PHP versions and extensions available.

 !     For an introduction to dependency management with Composer and
 !     how to get the most out of PHP on Heroku, refer to the docs at
 !     https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md and
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php

-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Installing platform packages...
       NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.lock; using PHP ^7.0.0
       - php (7.3.11)
       - apache (2.4.41)
       - nginx (1.16.1)
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 1.9.0 2019-08-02 20:55:32
-----> Preparing runtime environment...
       NOTICE: No Procfile, using 'web: heroku-php-apache2'.
-----> Checking for additional extensions to install...
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 18.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
       https://cogip-becode.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

This is the application log:

```
2019-11-08T12:59:03.464108+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/css/style.css" host=cogip-becode.herokuapp.com request_id=527c0174-09a9-42c9-9a08-4253b4baa78d fwd="84.198.194.106" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=128 protocol=https

2019-11-08T12:59:08.532874+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=cogip-becode.herokuapp.com request_id=d7eea251-3d27-49c5-bd54-75d9583b3dd4 fwd="84.198.194.106" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=279 protocol=https

2019-11-08T12:59:08.533394+00:00 app[web.1]: [08-Nov-2019 12:59:08 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /app/index.php on line 4

2019-11-08T12:59:08.533891+00:00 app[web.1]: [08-Nov-2019 12:59:08 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'cleardb' (T_STRING) in /app/database/connection.php on line 3

2019-11-08T12:59:08.534564+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.238.43 - - [08/Nov/2019:12:59:08 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "https://cogip-becode.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.9) Gecko/20100101 Goanna/4.4 Firefox/60.9 PaleMoon/28.7.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/354577)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/354577)